# Ants, this means war! Terro bait yum yum

Tags: pest-control, ants

I have been dealing with ants that just wont go away.  Found a mound near the foundation and killed it with poison.  These little boogers that are back now, I see where they are coming/going through a crack under the counter, but I cant find their mound outside.  So I laid out another bit of Terro ant bait.  They love this stuff.  Just hope it finishes them off.  Not sure what kind of ants these are. I generally keep my sink & counter wiped down each night before bed, but not yesterday.  There were a few dishes with food on them in the sink.  This morning I wake up to see the army of ants swarming the Terro bait, so maybe this is curtains for them soon.  Isnt the idea behind bait that they take it back and feed it to the larvae and the ants get fed from the larvae?  Hence if the larvae are killed, the whole colony dies?

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't a home improvement question. It's about the mechanics and biology of killing a colony of ants. This _might_ be better suited at [biology.se] or perhaps [gardening.se] (check their on-topic rules before posting there).

Comment: What home improvement problem do you have? Please revise your title to ask a specific, clear, question. We're not a creative writing forum.

Comment: Downvoting because this post reads like a terrible advertising plug.

Answer (score 3):

They look small enough to be Pharoh ants.

Don't kill Pharohs with regular 'poison' baits. Once the colony thinks it's under attack, most of the workers will turn into queens & bud off new colonies. This is not good news.

You need to use a hormone-based bait which prevents them breeding.

This article from the British Pest Control Association explains in greater detail - [PestWatch: Pharaoh ants](https://bpca.org.uk/News-and-Blog/bpca-pestwatch-pharaoh-ants)

In the UK, they are always indoor ants, where you are if it's warmer they could be indoors or out. Indoors they will nest absolutely anywhere - behind the fridge, between the walls, under a plant pot [yup, they're small enough you can get a colony of a couple of hundred under a medium house-plant.]

Comment: Are those type of ants in the OP's location?  I have had issues with tiny ants, and using the liquid bait has taken repeated applications to get rid of them.  If I laxed at all, they seem to rise in numbers.  Marking your calendar and doing this like every 5 days for a few months might be effective.

Comment: I had them once, we got pest control in rather than guessing [which is the only reason I knew this] - dry granule bait traps, left in place for a month. Never seen them again.